# JQuery selector simply select

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change a tag of a html element.

HTML

```
 <div id='content'>
 <g transform="100">.....</g>
 <g transform="150">This needs to stay as is</g>
 </div>
```

How do I change the transform value of the first  element? I have the following so far...

```
 $('#content g:first').replaceWith( "hello" );
```

Obviously this changes everything from the  to the end  where I only need to change the transform value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `attr` method:

```
$('#content g:first').attr('transform', 'newValue');
```

However if your document type is HTML `g` is not a valid tag, and `transform` is not a valid attribute, you can use `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: Well its for the jVectorMap plugin and I cannot figure out how to zoom into europe. But this seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content g:first').attr("transform", "hello");
```

Comment: Awesome. Knew it was nice an simple! I think after a coffee I would of got it lol

Answer (score 0):

*attr* method will do the work for you